# Why is the query string in my funnel step ignored?

Tags: google-analytics

I have two goals, one have a funnel step like:

```
/site/folder/
```

and the other is

```
/site/folder/?id=true
```

However, the goals treats the steps as identical, so I don't get distinct results.

[image]

How do I get the step to recognize the query string as being different?

Comment: How did you configure your goal? Please post a screenshot. You likely have to use either an exact match use Regex. Don't use "Begins with" because that could be what's skewing your goals.

Comment: The steps don't give the options you've described, only the destination URL field does. The URLs in the step fields for the funnel don't have this option.

Comment: Please post screenshot.

Comment: Added an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a regex match instead, so if your first goal step 1 is on /site/folder/ and your second step 1 is on /site/folder/?query=something, then use Regex:

```
Goal 1, Step 1:
Regex: ^\/site\/folder\/$

Goal 1, Destination:
Regex: ^\/some\/other\/stuff$

Goal 2, Step 1:
Regex: ^\/site\/folder\/\?query=.*$

Goal 2, Destination (same as for Goal 1):
Regex: ^\/some\/other\/stuff$
```

Comment: I'm trying this now.

Comment: There is no need to escape forward slashes (`/`). Only backward slash is reserved.